# Spring boot : Serializable Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, serializable

I am developing a forgot password service but getting a serializable Exception in getting data from the database. I am not able to find the solution for this. Please help me out.

StudentProfile.java

```
package sgsits.cse.dis.model;
import java.time.Year;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student_profile")
public class StudentProfile {

private long id;
private String createdBy;
private Date createdDate;
private String modifiedBy;
private Date modifiedDate;
private String enrollmentId;
private String password;
private boolean enabled;
private String resetToken;
private String fullName;
private Year admissionYear;
private String courseId;
private long mobileNo;
private String email;
private Date dob;
private String fatherName;
private long fatherContact;
private String motherName;
private long motherContact;
private String category;
private String gender;
private String bloodGroup;
private String nationality;
private Date lastLogin;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "Created_by")
public String getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
}
public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

@Column(name = "Created_date")
public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}
public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

@Column(name = "Modified_by")
public String getModifiedBy() {
    return modifiedBy;
}
public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
    this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
}

@Column(name = "modified_date")
public Date getModifiedDate() {
    return modifiedDate;
}
public void setModifiedDate(Date modifiedDate) {
    this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
}

@Column(name = "Enrollment_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
public String getEnrollmentId() {
    return enrollmentId;
}
public void setEnrollmentId(String enrollmentId) {
    this.enrollmentId = enrollmentId;
}

@Column(name = "Password", nullable = false)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Column(name = "Enabled")
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

@Column(name = "Reset_token")
public String getResetToken() {
    return resetToken;
}
public void setResetToken(String resetToken) {
    this.resetToken = resetToken;
}

@Column(name = "FullName")
public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}
public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

@Column(name = "Admission_Year")
public Year getAdmissionYear() {
    return admissionYear;
}
public void setAdmissionYear(Year admissionYear) {
    this.admissionYear = admissionYear;
}

@Column(name = "Course_Id")
public String getCourseId() {
    return courseId;
}
public void setCourseId(String courseId) {
    this.courseId = courseId;
}

@Column(name = "Mobile_No")
public long getMobileNo() {
    return mobileNo;
}
public void setMobileNo(long mobileNo) {
    this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
}

@Column(name = "Email")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Column(name = "DOB")
public Date getDob() {
    return dob;
}
public void setDob(Date dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

@Column(name = "Father_name")
public String getFatherName() {
    return fatherName;
}
public void setFatherName(String fatherName) {
    this.fatherName = fatherName;
}

@Column(name = "Father_contact")
public long getFatherContact() {
    return fatherContact;
}
public void setFatherContact(long fatherContact) {
    this.fatherContact = fatherContact;
}

@Column(name = "Mother_name")
public String getMotherName() {
    return motherName;
}
public void setMotherName(String motherName) {
    this.motherName = motherName;
}

@Column(name = "Mother_contact")
public long getMotherContact() {
    return motherContact;
}
public void setMotherContact(long motherContact) {
    this.motherContact = motherContact;
}

@Column(name = "Category")
public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}
public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

@Column(name = "Gender", nullable = false)
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

@Column(name = "Blood_group", nullable = false)
public String getBloodGroup() {
    return bloodGroup;
}
public void setBloodGroup(String bloodGroup) {
    this.bloodGroup = bloodGroup;
}

@Column(name = "Nationality", nullable = false)
public String getNationality() {
    return nationality;
}
public void setNationality(String nationality) {
    this.nationality = nationality;
}

@Column(name = "Last_login")
public Date getLastLogin() {
    return lastLogin;
}
public void setLastLogin(Date lastLogin) {
    this.lastLogin = lastLogin;
}

}
```

AuthenticationController.java

```
package sgsits.cse.dis.controller;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import sgsits.cse.dis.model.StudentProfile;
import sgsits.cse.dis.repo.StudentRepository;
import sgsits.cse.dis.service.StudentService;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")     //enables cross origin request
@RestController  
@RequestMapping(value = "/dis")   //url mapping for home page
@Api(value = "StudentSignUp Resource", description = "Student Sign Up Request")
public class AuthenticationController {

@Autowired
StudentRepository studRepo;

@ApiOperation(value = "forgot-password", response = Object.class, httpMethod = "POST")
@RequestMapping(value = "/forgot-password", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public boolean ForgotPassword(@RequestBody StudentProfile studPro)
{
    System.out.println(studPro.getEmail());
    List<StudentProfile> list = studRepo.findByEmail(studPro.getEmail());
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("We didn't find an account for that e-mail address.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("A password reset link has been sent to " + studPro.getEmail());
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

StudentRepository.java

```
package sgsits.cse.dis.repo;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import sgsits.cse.dis.model.StudentProfile;

@Repository("studentRepository")
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentProfile, Long>{
List<StudentProfile> findByEmail(String email);
List<StudentProfile> findByResetToken(String resetToken);
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>sgsits.cse</groupId>
<artifactId>dis</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>dis</name>
<description>Departmental Informatin System</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Stacktrace

```
divyanigarg09@gmail.com
2018-11-26 18:10:26.571  INFO 6004 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: select studentpro0_.id as id1_1_, studentpro0_.admission_year as admissio2_1_, studentpro0_.blood_group as blood_gr3_1_, studentpro0_.category as category4_1_, studentpro0_.course_id as course_i5_1_, studentpro0_.created_by as created_6_1_, studentpro0_.created_date as created_7_1_, studentpro0_.dob as dob8_1_, studentpro0_.email as email9_1_, studentpro0_.enabled as enabled10_1_, studentpro0_.enrollment_id as enrollm11_1_, studentpro0_.father_contact as father_12_1_, studentpro0_.father_name as father_13_1_, studentpro0_.full_name as full_na14_1_, studentpro0_.gender as gender15_1_, studentpro0_.last_login as last_lo16_1_, studentpro0_.mobile_no as mobile_17_1_, studentpro0_.modified_by as modifie18_1_, studentpro0_.modified_date as modifie19_1_, studentpro0_.mother_contact as mother_20_1_, studentpro0_.mother_name as mother_21_1_, studentpro0_.nationality as nationa22_1_, studentpro0_.password as passwor23_1_, studentpro0_.reset_token as reset_t24_1_ from student_profile studentpro0_ where studentpro0_.email=?
2018-11-26 18:10:28.353 ERROR 6004 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize] with root cause

java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303137
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:28) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:247) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:333) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1747) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1673) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1562) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:732) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:991) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:392) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1490) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:129) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:602) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.findByEmail(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sgsits.cse.dis.controller.AuthenticationController.ForgotPassword(AuthenticationController.java:64) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

I have tried number of solution like implementing serializable class, marker interface, but not at all able to find the solution. Also, searched all the related questions but those not helped me at all.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you call `findByResetToken` ?

Comment: Hibernate considers that one of the column is supposed to contain a serialized Java object. I doubt that you intend to store serialized Java objects in the database. My guess is that this is due to the property of type Year, which Hibernate doesn't know how to properly read from the database. Use an int (or an Integer if it's nullable). Or write a converter for this type.

Comment: @Arnaud Yes, having same problem with findByResetToken

Comment: @JBNizet Hey changing Year to int works! Thanks

Comment: Could you add  implements Serializable  to you entity ?

Comment: @TinyOS implements Serializable didn't work.